# Check if variable is infinity

Tags: compare, ocaml

I'm writing program in which exists adding variables, which may be infinity. In some place `neg_infinity + infinity` should be `neg_infinity` or `infinity`, so I'm trying to make 'if' to guarantee correct result. But I don't know how to check, if variable is infinity.
Simple `if variable = infinity` is wrong, cause `infinity = infinity` and `infinity != infinity`. [Example](https://ideone.com/nK9mHa). Fragment:

```
let p = 42. /. 0.;;

if p = infinity then
    print_string "Yes!\n"
else
    print_string "NO!\n";;

if p != infinity then
    print_string "Yes!\n"
else
    print_string "NO!\n";;
```

prints double "YES". Even `p <= infinity` and `p >= infinity`.
My idea is to check, if `p >= infinity` (I believe, that only infinity may satisfies that inequality.), but I don't know if it will be correct always. 
Also checked `==`, but doesn't work, as expected.

I don't know, how correctly resolve it in OCaml, so how it should be implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `!=` for inequality, use `<>`.

```
# let p = 42. /. 0.;;
val p : float = infinity
# p = infinity;;
- : bool = true
# p <> infinity;;
- : bool = false
#
```

General purpose equality is `=`.
General purpose inequality is `<>`.

Special purpose (strange and unpleasant) equality is `==`.
Special purpose (strange and unpleasant) inequality is `!=`.

(I'm kidding a little bit, but not so much.)

Comment: At the university has been said, "use whatever you want". And I was punished for doing without thinking. Thank you.